# Нужна помощь в установке композера

Tags: php, сервер, composer, установка, openserver

Недавно наткнулся на composer, а установить не могу, командную консоль никогда не использовал. Установка с офф. сайта ни в какую не работает.
Помогите пожалуйста установить для OpenServer'а и для хостинга.
Сможете еще объяснить что означает "глобальная установка"?
[image: ту ли cmd я использую?]

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/download/ тут качаем для винды установку- Download and run Composer-Setup.exe - it will install the latest composer version whenever it is executed.

Comment: Работать потом через cmd

Comment: Именно то, как дальше работать в сmd с композером меня и интересует

Comment: Ну там есть инструкция. Самое простое - заходите в проводнике в папку проекта. В стрке адреса в проводнике вместо адреса пишете cmd. Командная строка откроется сразу в этой диреектории. Ну или cd делайте ручками. Ну а дальше... Например composer require

Comment: C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\Projects\trainingcms>composer require

"php" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Что это может значить? Написал ваш пример "composer require"

Comment: просто `composer require` и enter. а вообще хреново вы установили, видно.

Comment: @n.osennij хреново установил из-за расположения проекта? я так понимаю надо в директорию опенсервера устанавливать? кажется, мне вас не понять, спасибо и на этом

Comment: Нет. composer устанавливается глобально в систему. И его можно вызвать из командной строки windows. При установке composers нужно указать интерпретатор Php - путь к нему. Читайте - там всё есть.

Comment: @сергейачадовский вы же из под Опенсервера работаете? У него композер уже установлен. Открываете консоль по закладке в `Опенсервер>Меню>Дополнительно>Консоль` Вы увидите текущую директорию, в которой установлен ваш Опенсервер _(у меня он установлен в d:\openserver)_ Выполняте комманду `composer help` и перед вами откроется справочное окошко по композеру. Если всё прошло именно так, как я описал - композер у вас работает, и максимум что вам надо будет сделать, так это обновить его версию командой _(если не ошибаюсь)_ `composer update`.

Comment: @сергейачадовский но кроме команд композера вам надо ознакомиться с консольными командами для перемещения по каталогам, и для манипулирования файлами. Их не много, и некоторые из них даже  похожи на пхпшные.

Answer (score 2):

Убеждаемся, что версия PHP не ниже **5.3**, допустим что стоит 5.6.

Открываем Дополнительно -> Конфигурация -> PHP 5.6

Ищем строку **extension=php_openssl.dll** и убеждаемся, что она не закомментирована (не стоит точка с запятой перед строкой).

Открываем Дополнительно -> Консоль, переходим к текущему модулю PHP:

```
cd modules/php/PHP-5.6/
```

Затем выполняем команду:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

Если успех, то в консоли видим примерно следующее:

*All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading 1.2.0...
Composer successfully installed to: C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6\composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar*

Проверяем какая версия стоит командой:

```
php composer.phar -V
```

В ответ можем получить что-то вроде:

*Composer version 1.2.0 2016-07-19 01:28:52*

Следующая команда создает .bat файл для краткости обращения к Composer:

```
echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat
```

Проверяем:

```
composer -V
```

Если всё в порядке и вы снова видите версию, значит дальше можно вместо `php composer.phar` пользоваться просто `composer`.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, самый простой способ проверить, установлен композер или нет, это ввод команды `composer`, и по ответу в консоли сразу станет ясно - если он установлен, вы увидите его логотип:

```
   ______                                          
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /    
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, многое понял, много нового и неизведанного для себя узнал. 
Долго писало ошибку в терминале когда вводил "composer" и ему подобные команды, потом просто  отредактировал переменную среду PATH(указал путь к моей версии php в openserver и поднял вверх для повышенного приоритета) и дальше уже из любой точки спокойно смог пользоваться композером. Как оказалось, не надо было его вообще устанавливать, из-за установки-то у меня и перестало работать, т.к. в ОпенСервере уже все есть.